# Is the code associated to the .L2 label of assembly code called procedurally in this segment?

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

I am trying to analyse the following code in assembly.

```
sub $48, %esp
mov $56, 44(%esp)
mov $3, 40(%esp)
mov $0, 36(%esp)
mov 44(%esp), %eax
mov %eax, 32(%esp)
jmp .L2
.L3:
mov 32(%esp), %eax
sub 40(%esp), %eax
mov %eax, 32(%esp)
add $1, 36(%esp)
.L2:
mov 32(%esp), %eax
cmp 40(%esp), %eax
ja .L3
mov 36(%esp),%eax
mov 32(%esp),%edx
```

If my understanding is clear, the first 6 lines are called normally, and then the program jumps to .L2: and executes the code. If R[eax] == R[40 + R[esp], then the code will go to .L3.

My question is about what happens after this. Is .L3 executed and then the code goes to .L2 because it is right after it, or does it automatically jumps to the last two lines after executing .L3?

Additionally, I could use some tips about reading assembly code; I am trying to find the final values of eax and edx.

Thank you

Comment: Ive been trying to figure out what the L stands for? Layer? Do you know? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct: after jumping to .L3, all 6 instructions between there and ja .L3 will be executed in order, and that process will repeat itself until the conditional jump isn't taken.

Sounds like you're doing fine reading the code :)

Comment: Thanks! This clears up a lot for me.
Still, I have trouble understanding what happens with, for instance,   mov $56, 44(%esp).

What happens to esp there? Isn't 56 a value that is too big to be placed in a 5-bit register?

Comment: First, esp is 32 bit wide. Second it is not changed at all. The instruction moves the value 56 into a memory adress 44 bytes above esp.

Comment: Sorry, my understanding is still very low. So that means esp is represented by the 32 bits following it's location?
i.e.
mov 16(%esp), $9 would write 9 starting at the 16th bit of esp?

Comment: %esp is a register (a distinct piece of storage from memory); your "mov $56, 44(%esp)" would move the 32-bit value of $56 to the 4 bytes starting at the address computed by adding the contents of %esp to the value 44.

Comment: Thank you that was very clear! So in the end I get eax = 0 and edx = 56, it is starting to make sense